# How to access Vue 3 global properties from the store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3

In Vue 2 I used to import Vue and access global properties like this (from the store):

```
import Vue from 'vue'    
Vue.config.myGlobalProperty
```

According to the [new documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties), in Vue 3 the global properties are declared using the `app` object returned by `createApp`:

```
const app = createApp({})
app.config.globalProperties.myGlobalProperty
```

And then accessed in the child component by simply calling `this.myglobalProperty`

But how to access that global property from the store? I tried exporting/importing the app object but it doesn't work (probably due to the app being created after its import in the store).

With Vue 2 I used to use global properties in the store like this:
Declaration in the `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.config.myglobalProperty = 'value'
```

Usage in the store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.config.myglobalProperty
```

Is there a good way to do that in Vue3?

I noticed a better way to [provide/inject properties](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity) but it works with child component only and not with the store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the `app` instance to a *store factory*:

```js
// store.js
import { createStore as createVuexStore } from 'vuex'

export const createStore = (app) => {
  return createVuexStore({
    actions: {
      doSomething() {
        if (app.config.globalProperties.myGlobal) {
          //...
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

And use it in `main.js` like this:

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from './store'

const app = createApp({})
const store = createStore(app)
app.use(store)
app.mount('#app')
```

If your store modules need access to the `app` instance, you could use the same technique above with a *module factory*:

```js
// moduleA.js
export default (app) => {
  return {
    namespaced: true,
    actions: {
      doSomething() {
        if (app.config.globalProperties.myOtherGlobal) {
          //...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And import it into your store like this:

```js
// store.js
import moduleA from './moduleA'
import { createStore as createVuexStore } from 'vuex'

export const createStore = (app) => {
  return createVuexStore({
    modules: {
      moduleA: moduleA(app),
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use Vuex, etc., you can easily create your store via provide/inject on the application itself, as in the example (the example is simplified for understanding):

```
const createState = () => reactive({counter: 0, anyVariable: 1});
const state = createState();
const key = 'myState';

// example of reactivity outside a component
setInterval(() => {
  state.counter++;
}, 1000);

const app = createApp({});
app.provide('myState', state); // provide is used on the whole application
```

As you can see, your own store can be completely used outside the component.

Inside components, you can use (example):

```
  setup() {
  ...
    const globalState = inject('myStore'); // reactive => {counter: 0, anyVariable: 1}
  ...
    return {globalState, ...}
  }
```

Accordingly, you can have multiple stores in multiple Vue applications.

I hope this example will help you somehow.

Comment: Actually I do use Vuex and need to access the global properties from the Vuex store